# running hdfs dfsadmin commands in python

Tags: python, hadoop, hdfs

Looked at snakebite, it is an awesome python package for running `hadoop fs` set of commands

I have a need for running `hadoop dfsadmin` set of commands from within python. Writing tools that need to run commands like `hadoop dfsadmin -report` and `hadoop dfsadmin -refreshNodes`

So, to all the awesome python developers out there writing tooling on hadoop operational tasks, what is the recommended way to run these set of commands ?

Shelling out is very expensive, is there any other recommended approach/suggestion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to use hdfs thrift libraries.  I'm not sure how complete the library is, but here are a few links.  Your best bet is referencing Clouderas Hue libraries for Python.  I did see a function call for refreshNodes.

HDFS Thrift Page http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HDFS-APIs

Cloudera Hue library for HDFS - These are auto-generated by Thrift https://github.com/cloudera/hue/tree/master/desktop/libs/hadoop/gen-py/hadoop/api/hdfs

hdfs.thrift https://github.com/cloudera/hue/blob/master/desktop/libs/hadoop/java/if/hdfs.thrift

Comment: thanks for the answer.  though I havent got a chance to look through the code link in detail. it is interesting to know that thrift bindings can be generated to access hdfs. This probably means this can be done using protobufs as well?

Comment: It looks like both Snakebite has a protobufs interface as well.  You may be able to use that or implement your own.  I'm not sure of it's completeness however.  

https://github.com/apache/hadoop/tree/trunk/hadoop-hdfs-project/hadoop-hdfs/src/main/proto

Comment: yes snakebite uses protobufs, but my understanding is atleast given the current sate of its implementation; it does not support "hadoop dfsadmin" set of commands. I can not speak as to why not, but there might be reasons which I would not know without reading up on the hadoop source code.